# $\phi(t) = 1 + o(t^2)$ as $t \downarrow 0$, then $\phi(t) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In the title $\phi(t)$ is the characteristic function of some random variable. My question here is not really about how to prove this. As this is a question posted by my professor, I am wondering if there can be a typo in the question.

Namely, the part I am suspicious about being incorrect is the $t \downarrow 0$ part, my suspicion is that it should instead be $t \to 0$. Since if I have a $\phi$ such that $\phi(t) = 1$ for $t \geq 0$ and some other functional form so that $\phi(t) = 1 + o(t^2)$ is not satisfied when $t < 0$, then apparently this claim does not need to hold. For example, I can let $\phi(t)$ be some function that has an $o(t)$ term in it when $t < 0$. However, I am not sure if I am correct on this.

Hence, I am wondering if this $t \downarrow 0$ is enough to prove the claim or it should instead be $t \to 0$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might note that $\phi(-t) = \overline{\phi(t)}$, so if $\phi(t) = 1 + o(t^2)$ as $t \downarrow 0$, it is also true as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Ahh, I see!! Completely forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any (real) random variable. Then,
$$
\phi_{X}(0)=\mathbb{E}\exp\left\{ iX\cdot0\right\} =1.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\left|\phi_{X}(t)-\phi_{X}(s)\right|=\left|\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{ iXs\right\} \left(\exp\left\{ iX\left(t-s\right)\right\} -1\right)\right]\right|\leq\mathbb{E}\left|\exp\left\{ iX\left(t-s\right)\right\} -1\right|.
$$
By the DCT, the quantity on the right hand side of the inequality
above goes to zero as $t-s$ vanishes. Therefore, $\phi$ is continuous
(actually, uniformly continuous) and hence
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\phi(t)=1.
$$